# Socket bind with wildcard ip

Tags: c, linux, udp

I have a created a UDP socket and bind that socket to `inaddr_any (0.0.0.0)` and and some
well known port number. As per my understanding this socket can receive data over all the interfaces of the machine over the specified port number. 
But When i will call `send()`  it will use the default IP address as the source address.

- How is the default IP address chosen?
- If I want to use some other interface (other than the default) for sending the data, how can this be done?

Context of the problem:

I am implementing LDP protocol. It can have many hello adjacencies. Thus i am creating a server to recv data from the other interfaces of the router. Once the hello adjacency is formed, then hello messages are to sent be on the specific interface over UDP over which the hello adjacency is created.

Comment: Sounds like you need a socket per interface.

Answer (score 2):

The default IP address is chosen based on the network the packet is sent to. For example if you have two interfaces, one connected to network A and the other connected to network B, if you send a packet to network B the packet will be sent with the IP address of the second interface. For this reason, most of the time **you don't have to worry about it**.

If you have two network interfaces connected to the same network, you can `bind` the socket to the address of one of them, and the packet will go out with that address. For example, this will bind an IP socket to `192.168.122.1`, if allowed by the network stack:

```
struct sockaddr_in addr;
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.122.1");
addr.sin_port = 0;
if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr*) &addr, sizeof addr) == -1) {
    perror("bind");
}
```

Comment: If i bind the socket with a specific address, then surely this can be done. If i have bind the socket with 0.0.0.0 then is there a way to explicitly set the source address to used?

Comment: Yes, with `bind`. By default you can only bind to local addresses (that is, addresses configured on a local network interface) but there's an option you can set to allow binding to non-local IPs...

Comment: i cannot bind the same socket two times, one with 0.0.0.0 and the the calling bind again with different IP?

Comment: You can't bind a socket twice. If the socket has already been bound to an address, even if to 0.0.0.0, `bind` will fail with the `EINVAL` error.

Comment: Then How can i set the source IP other than default IP, if the socket is bind to 0.0.0.0?

Comment: You can't. Don't bind the socket to 0.0.0.0 if you want to bind it to some other address.

Comment: @SumitTrehan It might be helpful if you explained the problem you are trying to solve.  There is no obvious reason for you wanting to bind to all interfaces then pick which of many equally suitable interfaces to use for a given `send`

Comment: I am implementing LDP protocol. It can have many hello adjacencies. Thus i am creating a server to recv data from the other interfaces of the router. Once the hello adjacency is formed, then hello messages are to sent on the specific interface over UDP